# Sencha Touch Float/Move to Right

Tags: ipad, sencha-touch, extjs

I am using Sencha touch for the first time, I have managed to get some menu items to show, but I would like it to move/float to the right is anyone sure how to do this?

this is my code for the buttons:

```
spaceosaur.views.Home = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
initComponent: function(){

this.dockedItems = [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        title: 'Spaceosaur',
        items: [                 
            { xtype: 'segmentedbutton', items: [
              { iconMask: true, iconCls: '', text: 'Featured', pressed : true },
              { iconMask: true, text: 'Latest' },
              { iconMask: true, text: 'Popular' },
            ]},
            { iconMask: true, ui: 'action', text: 'Refresh' },

        ]
    }]

    spaceosaur.views.Home.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
}
```

});

Ext.reg('home', spaceosaur.views.Home);

And an example of site is here: http://cameronmlewis.com/pad/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to change the alignment of the buttons in a toolbar is to add [spacers](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.Spacer).

To align something to the right you could do the following:

```
 items: [
    {xtype: 'spacer'},
    { iconMask: true, ui: 'action', text: 'Refresh' }
 ]
```

The spacer would push everything to the right.  You could get creative with the flex & width properties of the spacer and/or the buttons to get everything to space out and line up properly.